# Do fox-wives have to give birth under a tree?

Tags: mythical-creatures, japanese, shinto

Kitsune are [born and give birth under a tree](http://tehlorri.com/l5r/birthtree.htm). The tree is then connected to the kitsune. The tree will gain power from the kitsune, never getting sick or being infested with worms or bug (don't know about cutting it down).

Kitsune, when they reach the year of 100 or 50, can shape-shift. Some kitsune shift into beautiful young women and might marry a human. These kitsune are known as fox-wives. They can have children together and if the child is human, will inherit powers.

If the kitsune is in human form, do they have to give birth to child under a tree? Does the tree get the same benefits if the child is human?

Comment: You may also want to look at Fox Spirits in Chinese mythology--major part of Chinese folklore